# DataTable Remove Rows Not Reflected in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I'm fairly new to C# and this has me stumped. My project is using DataTables and TableAdapters to connect to a SQL Server database. I have a method that opens Excel, builds a DataRow and then passes that to the method below which adds it to my DataTable (cdtJETS) via the TableAdapter (ctaJETS).

```
    public bool AddJETSRecord(DataRow JETSDataRow)
    {
        bool bolException = false;
        cdtJETS.BeginLoadData();
        // Add the data row to the table
        try
        {
            cdtJETS.ImportRow(JETSDataRow);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Log an exception
            bolException = true;
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        cdtJETS.EndLoadData();
        // If there were no errors and no exceptions, then accept the changes
        if (!cdtJETS.HasErrors && !bolException)
        {
            ctaJETS.Update(cdtJETS);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

The above works fine and the records show up in SQL Server as expected. I have another method that grabs a subset of the records in that DataTable and outputs them to another Excel file (this is a batch process that will collect records over time using the above method and then occasionally output them, so I can't directly move the data from the first Excel file to the second). After the second Excel file is updated I want to delete the records from the table so that they aren't duplicated the next time the method is run. This is where I'm having the issue:

```
    public bool DeleteJETSRecords(DataTable JETSData)
    {
        int intCounter = 0;
        DataRow drTarget;
        // Parse all of the rows in the JETS Data that is to be deleted
        foreach (DataRow drCurrent in JETSData.Rows)
        {
            // Search the database data table for the current row's OutputID
            drTarget = cdtJETS.Rows.Find(drCurrent["OutputID"]);
            // If the row is found, then delete it and increment the counter
            if (drTarget != null)
            {
                cdtJETS.Rows.Remove(drTarget);
                intCounter++;
            }
        }

        // Continue if all of the rows were found and removed
        if (JETSData.Rows.Count == intCounter && !cdtJETS.HasErrors)
        {
            cdtJETS.AcceptChanges();
            try
            {
                ctaJETS.Update(dtJETS);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
            cdtJETS.RejectChanges();
            return false;
    }
```

As I step through the method I can see the rows being removed from the DataTable (i.e. if JETSData has 10 rows, at the end cdtJETS has n-10 rows) and no exceptions are thrown, but after I AcceptChanges and Update the TableAdapter, the underlying records are still in my SQL Server table. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `Rows.Remove` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is equivalent to calling [the row's `Delete` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), followed by [the row's `AcceptChanges` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx).

As with [the `DataTable.AcceptChanges` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this indicates that the change has *already* been saved to the database. This is not what you want.

The following should work:

```
public bool DeleteJETSRecords(DataTable JETSData)
{
    int intCounter = 0;
    DataRow drTarget;
    // Parse all of the rows in the JETS Data that is to be deleted
    foreach (DataRow drCurrent in JETSData.Rows)
    {
        // Search the database data table for the current row's OutputID
        drTarget = cdtJETS.Rows.Find(drCurrent["OutputID"]);
        // If the row is found, then delete it and increment the counter
        if (drTarget != null)
        {
            drTarget.Delete();
            intCounter++;
        }
    }

    // Continue if all of the rows were found and removed
    if (JETSData.Rows.Count == intCounter && !cdtJETS.HasErrors)
    {
        // You have to call Update *before* AcceptChanges:
        ctaJETS.Update(dtJETS);
        cdtJETS.AcceptChanges();
        return true;
    }

    cdtJETS.RejectChanges();
    return false;
}
```